# How do I set an option value of type List<Object> in an InputSelect?

Tags: c#, forms, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I have the following models:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBrith { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
    public EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }


}

public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Other
}

public enum EmployeeType
{
    Developer,
    ProjectManager,
    Manager

}

public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ProjectStartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ProjectEndDate { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> AssignedDevelopers { get; set; } 
    public List<Ticket> ProjectTickets { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Priority ProjectPriority { get; set; }
}

public enum Priority
{
    High,
    Low,
    Medium,
    None
}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CompanyID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }

    public List<Address> CompanyAddress { get; set; }

    public string CompanyDescription { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following Form

```
@inject HttpClient client
<h3>Edit Projects</h3>
@if (companies == null)
{
    <text>Loading...</text>
}
else if (companies.Count == 0)
{
    <text>CANNOT CREATE PROJECT WITHOUT COMPANIES</text>
}
else
{
<EditForm Model="@project" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Company Name :</label>
        <div>
            <InputText @bind-Value="@project.ProjectName" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => project.ProjectName)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div>
            <label>Company Description:</label>
            <div>
                <InputText @bind-Value="@project.ProjectDescription" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => project.ProjectDescription)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div>
            <label>Project Start Date:</label>
            <div>
                <InputDate @bind-Value="@project.ProjectStartDate" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => project.ProjectStartDate)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div>
            <label>Project End Date:</label>
            <div>
                <InputDate @bind-Value="@project.ProjectEndDate" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => project.ProjectEndDate)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div>
            <label>Project Priority:</label>
            <div>
                <InputSelect @bind-Value="@project.ProjectPriority">
                    @foreach (var priority in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Priority)))
                        {
                        <option value="@priority">@priority</option>
                        }
                </InputSelect>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => project.ProjectPriority)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div>
            <label>Project Priority:</label>
            <div>
                <InputSelect @bind-Value="@project.CompanyId">
                    @foreach (var company in companies)
                        {
                        <option value="@company.CompanyID">@company.CompanyName</option>
                        }
                </InputSelect>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => project.CompanyId)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div>
            <label>Employee:</label>
            <div>
                <InputSelect @bind-Value="project.AssignedDevelopers">
                    @foreach (var developer in employees)
                        {
                        <option value="@employees.FindAll(e => e.EmployeeId == developer.EmployeeId).ToList()">@developer.Email</option>
                        }
                </InputSelect>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        @ButtonText
    </button>
</EditForm>
@code {
    List<Company> companies { get; set; }
    List<Employee> employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        companies = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Company>>("api/companies");
        employees = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Employee>>("api/employees");
    }
    [Parameter] public Project project { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Save";
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
   }
```

What I am trying to do is assign employee to a project using the form above.
However, It seems like when I select the employee It doesn't update the project with the selected employee.. Therefore, This:

```
    <div>
            <label>Employee:</label>
            <div>
                <InputSelect @bind-Value="project.AssignedDevelopers">
                    @foreach (var developer in employees)
                        {
                        <option value="@employees.FindAll(e => e.EmployeeId == developer.EmployeeId).ToList()">@developer.Email</option>
                        }
                </InputSelect>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

section of my form isn't working.. I am new to c# and not sure how to assign employees to projects.

Comment: Remove the `OnValidSubmit` parameter and replace it with a method to handle the form submission, ie. `void OnValidSubmit(EditContext context){ /* write developer assignment back to api here */ }`

Comment: Can you provide an example ? How would Do I retrieve the object selected and add it to context ?

Comment: the **InputSelect** is used only to assign one value I think that the **AssignedDevelopers**  members should not be a  List Object. Here is an example to use an **InputSelect** https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-inputselect-component-for-enumerations-in-blazor.htm